# What does ::SomeClass reference in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Take the following code sample:

```kotlin
class Food(var size: Int, val doSomething: () -> Unit) {
    init {
        var t = 0
    }

    operator fun invoke() {
        doSomething()
    }
}

var x = ::Food
x.invoke(10) {
    var x = 1
}
```

When `x.invoke(10)` is called, the init in Food is called. But the invoke function is not called. This seems odd. What is `::Food` referencing and what exactly is `x.invoke` calling if the actual invoke function is not even being called?

It appears that x refers to the constructor. You can call the constructor by just calling:

`x(10) {}`

But including the `.invoke` does nothing. The constructor still gets called (and hence the init) but the invoke function itself does nothing. Not even sure why this is even allowed.

I have a feeling that `.invoke` is calling Kotlin's own built-in invoke function and NOT the operator function that is in the class.

Comment: ::SomeClass is a syntax for [Constructor references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#constructor-references)

Comment: Thanks. Yes you're correct. The Kotlin docs didn't cover this in the section lamda functions where it is first mentioned but mention it under Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

the invoke function can be called by writing `()` behind an instance of the class. so simply writing

```
x.invoke(10) {
    println("test")
}()
```

could work for your example and prints "test". Or this for example

```
val s = x.invoke(10) {
    println("test")
}

s()
s()
```

prints test twice

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that `x` refers to the constructor.

Your observation is correct. `x(10) {}` and `x.invoke(10) {}` are indeed the same. The former is just a syntactic sugar for the latter, in the same way that `1 + 1` is just a syntactic sugar for `1.plus(1)`.

In fact, this is the whole point of the `invoke` operator, and the reason why you can directly call function/constructor references. If `x` has declared an `invoke(...)` operator, then `x(...)` means `x.invoke(...)`.

`::Food`, being a reference to the constructor of `Food`, is of type `KFunction2<Int, () -> Unit, Food>`. This type is specified to have a `invoke()` operator that takes an `Int` and `() -> Unit`, and returns a `Food`. When you do `x(10) {}` or `x.invoke(10) {}`, you are calling *that* `invoke` operator, not the one in `Food`.

To call the `invoke` in `Food`, you need an instance of `Food`, which is exactly what `x(10) {}` or `x.invoke(10) {}` returns.

```
x(10) {
    println("foo")
}.invoke()

// or

x(10) {
    println("foo")
}()
```

Either of the above would print "foo".